# Is this euphemism from scripture?

Tags: caste-system

A lady in a YouTube video says "fourth varna" to refer to the varna said to be born from Purusha's feet.  Does scripture use this euphemism anywhere?

Comment: its already answered.purusha suksha has it

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee Purusha Suktam says "Padbhyagm shudro ajayata"

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes, fourth varna is sudra! i cd nt get what op wants

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee He wants to know if the euphemism "fourth varna" is used in scriptures. In other words, he wants to know if Shudras are referred to as "fourth varna" in the scriptures and not by the word "Shudra" directly.

Comment: @Ikshvaku omg! that i think is very clear!

Comment: post link to source video

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this?:

> To a Vaisya pertain in addition agriculture, trade, animal husbandry,
>   and lending money on interest.
>
> **The Sudra is the fourth class with a single birth.** Speaking the truth, refraining from anger, and purification apply to him also.
>   52According to some, he should simply wash his hands and feet in place
>   of sipping water. 53He should make ancestral offerings; 54support his
>   dependants; 55be faithful to his wife;
>
> **Gautama Smriti 10.51.49-56**

Comment: that is just denoting the number '4'. what OP is asking is why people refer it to by number instead of name. and answer to that is brahmin-hatred-movement started by pseduo-atheists in tamilnadu.

Comment: Let OP see my answer and decide ..@ram

Comment: No - I am asking is "fourth varna" in the same category as "Harujan", "Dalit" etc. @rickross.

Comment: @SK Shudra are the 4th and last varna in Sanatana.  The rest avarna/panchama/harijan/outcaste/dalit/descendant of varna sankar(mostly) all refer to those who aren’t members of Hindu samaj and are like people of other religions and races etc.  But Shudra are part of Hindu society.  Confusion is deliberately caused by activists clubbing Shudra with these, tribals etc for political advantage and also Other Backward Class is a new euphemism for Shudra..but all scriptures mention them as Shudra not numbering them.